# Why zoom in (css) in via jQuery does not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

I know this is maybe a stupid question, but I've researched a lot and do not find why. I have implemented 2 simple jQuery functions for zoom out and zoom in

```
$("#zoomOutBtn").click(function(){
    var zoom = $("#treeContainer").css("zoom");
    zoom = ((zoom - 0.1) * 100) + "%";
    $("#myDiv").css("zoom", zoom);
  });

  $("#zoomInBtn").click(function(){
    var zoom = $("#treeContainer").css("zoom");
    zoom = ((zoom + 0.1) * 100) + "%";
    $("#myDiv").css("zoom", zoom);
  });
```

The thing is that zooming out works, but zooming in does not unless run before zoom out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` is overloaded, it means addition when you use it with numbers, but *concatenation* when you use it where at least one operand is a string. The value you get from `css` is a *string*, so `zoom + 0.1` will end up appending the characters `0`, `.`, and `1` to the end of the string (e.g., `100%0.1` or whatever), not adding the value `0.1` to it.

To fix it, convert to number first:

```
zoom = ((parseFloat(zoom) + 0.1) * 100) + "%";
```

(I used `parseFloat` there to allow for browsers that include the `%` in the value that comes back. `parseFloat` stops at the first invalid character, whereas `Number(zoom)` or `+zoom` would result in `NaN` in that case. Looking at your code, though, you might need a branch specifically to deal with that case, as the math would be different.)

The reason `zoom - 0.1` works is that `-`, unlike `+`, isn't overloaded; it only has a numeric meaning. So it implicitly coerces its arguments to number, where `+` won't if either operand is a string.

Comment: Yeah, big mistake of mine. Thanks. I'll take a deep look into it.